# How to make switch between menu items with ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have tree-like(there can be different number of levels) structure and need to create menu from it.Here are main methods from Menu component and menuItem component:

```
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='Tema-menu-container'>                   
                <ul className='Tema-menuItems-list'>
                    <li className='Tema-menuItem'>
                        <a>
                            <Icon className='Tema-menuItem-iconBack' name='caret left' size='small'/> Back
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    {this.getMenuItems()}
                </ul>
            </div>


        )
    }

    getMenuItems= ( selectedItemId ) => {
        let  menu_items = [];
        let  items = this.items2;

        for(let group in  items) {
            for (let subgroup in  items[group]) {                   
                for(let group2 in  items[group][subgroup]) {                        
                    if(typeof items[group][subgroup][group2].id != 'undefined') {
                        menu_items.push(
                            <LeftSideMenuItem key     = {items[group][subgroup][group2].id}
                                              item    = {items[group][subgroup][group2]}
                                              onClick = { this.menuItemClick}
                            />
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return menu_items;
    };
```

And component for items. Every item has level and sublevels:

```
    render() {
        let {item} = this.props;                

        return (

                <li key={item.id}>
                    <a>
                        {item.title} <Icon  name='angle right' size='small'/>
                    </a>
                    <ul className='Tema-subMenuItems-list'>
                        {this.getGroups(item.groups)}
                        {this.getMeasures(item.measures)}
                    </ul>
                </li>
        )
    }

    getGroups = (groups) => {
        let groupsSubMenu = [];
        if (groups.length != 0) {               
                groups.forEach((item, i, groups) =>{
                console.log(item);
                groupsSubMenu.push(
                    <li key={item.id}>
                        <a>
                            { item.title } <Icon  name='angle right' size='small' />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                );
            });
        }
        return groupsSubMenu;
    };

    getMeasures = (measures) => {
        let measuresSubMenu = [];
        if (measures.length != 0) {
            measures.forEach((item, i, measures) =>{
                console.log(item);
                measuresSubMenu.push(
                    <li key={item.id} >
                        <a>
                            { item.title } <Icon  name='angle right' size='small' />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                );
            });
        }
        return measuresSubMenu;
    }
}
```

I need to make something like itemClick which will allow to walk between menu levels,but I have no idea how to perform it logically, and I have doubt about my code. How can I organize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this.props.onClick` in your menu items `onClick` or some other method like below,

```
getGroups = (groups) => {
    let groupsSubMenu = [];
    if (groups.length != 0) {               
        groups.map((item, i) => groupsSubMenu.push(
            <li key={item.id} onClick={this.props.onClick}>
                <a>{ item.title } <Icon  name='angle right' size='small' /></a>
            </li>
        ));
    }
    return groupsSubMenu;
};
```

And you can pass item it through `onClick` to access specific menu item.

Comment: I need to perform another thing. For example I have structure 'id' : 1,
 'title' : 'Dashboard',
 'groups' : [
 {
  'id' : 3,
  'title' : 'Measure Group 2',
  'groups' : [
   {
    'id' : 4,
    'title' : 'Measure Group 4',
    'groups' : [],
    'measures' : [
     {
      'id' : 6,
      'title' : 'Measure 3'
     },
     {
      'id' : 7,
      'title' : 'Measure 4'
     }
    ]
   }
  ],
  'measures' : [
   {
    'id' : 18,
    'title' : 'Measure 18'
   }
  ]
 }

According to my code I render: Measure Group 2
Measure Group 4
Measure 18

Comment: so I render Measure Group 2
Measure Group 4
Measure 18
with on click I must hide them and show only Measure 3,Measure 4